# org.hibernate.AnnotationException:@OneToOne on com.abc.dto.Test.name references an unknown entity: com.abc.type.TestName

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity which has reference to another entity where its failing.
Using Spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot: 2.0.5
spring form: 5.0.9

```
package com.abc.dto

@Entity
@Table(name="Test_Table")
@SequenceGenerator(name="seq",sequenceName="TEST_SEQUENCE")
public class Test {

private TestName name;

@JoinColumn
@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
public TestName getName(return name);
}
```

> Error: org.hibernate.AnnotationException:@OneToOne on
> com.abc.dto.Test.name references an unknown entity:
> com.abc.type.TestName

com.abc.type.TestName is part of a jar

```
package com.abc.type
@Entity
@Table(name="Test_name")
public class TestName{
//code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in you `Test` class:

```
@JoinColumn
@OneToOne(targetEntity = TestName.class)
private TestName name;
```

Comment: Tried above solution but it throws the same error.

Comment: Can you share a testable git repo to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably due to the package not being scanned properly or the new entity not being declared in the persistence.xml or orm.xml. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/domain/EntityScan.html